# Calling Stored Proc in EF 6 with output parameters?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an MVC 5 project that I'm trying to figure out how to call an Oracle stored proc that has output parameters. I've done some searching and this is the closest I've come but I get an error that it is invalid SQL.

Even if I get it to run successfully, I'm assuming it will pass the out put values to the results object and have an IsValid and Remarks properties populated?

```
public class ValidateCSPolicyResult
{
    public string IsValid { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}

using (var ctx = new DataContext())
{

    var empId = new SqlParameter("@empId", employeeId);
    var startDate = new SqlParameter("@startDate", startDateTime);
    var endDate = new SqlParameter("@endDate", endDateTime);
    var swapEmpId = new SqlParameter("@swapEmpId", swapEmployeeId);

    var isValid = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "Valid",
        Value = "N",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };

    var remarks = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "Remarks",
        Value = "",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };


    var results = ctx.Database.SqlQuery(ValidateCSPolicyResult)("VALIDATE_CSW_POLICY  @empId, @startDate, @endDate, @swapEmpId, @Valid out, @Remarks out").FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Comment: You'll want to call Database.ExecuteSqlCommand and then examine the output parameters after the call to get the returned values.

Comment: ExecutSqlCommand doesn't seem to work either. When I converted to that I get a message that the non-generic method and not be used with type arguments.